# Ubuntu 18.04, networking static routing

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing

I need to set up a small computing cluster consisting of 4 computing nodes (4x ubuntu 18.04). I have a problem creating a connection from workers to the WAN. All computers has static ip 10.1.1.X(1-4), where the head node (10.1.1.1) has also additional NIC connected to the other network (192.168.X.X). This head node should be the entry point to the system. However, I have problem connecting from worker node e.g 10.1.1.4 to the network ( ping 192.168.X.X). I know that I should probably create a router on the head node, but do not know where to start.

Currently my netconfig for the head node is:

```
network:   
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno2:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.2.98/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [192.168.2.2, 192.168.2.3]
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.1.1.1/24]
      gateway4: 10.1.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: []
```

Do you have any suggestions? Please note that I do not have much experiences with network settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on the head node, because your router (the one after the head node in the connection chain to outer network) does not know how to access addresses in `10.0.0.0/8` range.

Another option (simpler, but may be unsupported by your router model) is to add a static routing entry on the router to access `10.0.0.0/8` via `192.168.2.98` (the head node address that the router knows).